# Is the Dunning-Kruger effect reversed in Japan?

Tags: psychology, japan

Wikipedia seems to [claim](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dunning%E2%80%93Kruger_effect#Cultural_differences_in_self-perception) so citing a single study:

> The study "Divergent Consequences of Success and Failure in Japan and North America: An Investigation of Self-improving Motivations and Malleable Selves" (2001) indicated that **Japanese people tended to underestimate their abilities**, and tended to see underachievement (failure) as an opportunity to improve their abilities at a given task, thereby increasing their value to the social group

I'm betting there have been other studies of the  Dunning-Kruger effect since 2001 in Japan. So is the highlighted conclusion of the aforementioned paper still true?

Comment: I've never seen any suggestion that the Dunning-Kruger effect is universal, nor that there are not people who experience the opposite effect.  The graph shown in your link illustrates both extremes.

Comment: I feel it's worth pointing out that the reverse of the Dunning-Kruger effect is called "[impostor syndrome](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Impostor_syndrome)".

Comment: Seems in accord with the aesthetic of wabi-sabi ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wabi-sabi ).  Kintsugi ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kintsugi ) is definitely a concept that could usefully be applied to people as well as pottery!